# JanusGraph cannot connect to remote elasticsearch cluster

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

We previously had JG (v0.5.2) up and running without any issues using HBASE as our backend storage. To try and speed up queries we stood up an elasticsearch cluster, however now our JG instance is not starting up, saying that "could not get type for name org.janusgraph.example.GraphApp".

[image]

Our elastic properties are setup like:

```
index.search.backend="elasticsearch"
index.search.hostname = "myhost.elasticsearch:9200"  ## https://myhost.elasticsearch:9200/janusgraph  <-- returns index values
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=true
```

In order to hit ES using curl, I have to run with the -k flag

> curl -k https://myhost.elasticsearch:9200

I assume there has to be an option like that for JG, no?

I've been banging my head on this one for a while. Is there anything that I am missing??

Comment: The error in your question does not suggest a problem with being able to connect to or properly authenticate with ElasticSearch.  Any problem of that sort would lead to either a connection time out or some error message relating to networking. The equivalent of the `-k` flag would only help if you were getting some sort of SSL certificate verification error.  What you're getting sounds like a fundamental problem with how your application is built or configured.

Comment: btw...please do not supply textual information by way of an image.  Rather, you should copy/paste the text of the message into your question and format it so that it readable.  I wanted to do a Google search for the error you're getting, but I couldn't copy/paste from the error message, so I passed on doing that.  This is one reason to not supply images.

Comment: @CryptoFool - I spoke with a coworker that said they had to setup a truststore in order to connect to the ES cluster.  I'm not too familiar with that which is why I was hoping there was an option to not check the cert (like the -k flag)

Comment: There may be such an option.  I still think that your problem has nothing to do with anything you just said.  Being unable to connect to ES isn't what's causing this problem.  I mean, it's remotely possible, like if your app were catching network error exceptions and then doing something completely different if a network error occurs, and that completely different thing is broken.  But even then, it is not ES or the network that is causing this problem.  It would just be that a properly working ES would mask this problem.